# PWA websites stopped showing "Install To Home Screen" and "Push Notification" dialogs

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

On Android chrome browser if I use to open PWA websites like pinterest, tinder, grubhub it use to show Install to home screen and later enable push notification dialogs.

We're in process of changing our website to PWA, is there something changed with chrome on android or android OS policy  ?

Comment: Still works fine. What website URL is not working for you? Does that HTTPS url pass all Chrome Lighthouse PWA tests?

Comment: I've tested pinterest, flipkart, myntra and not all parameters are passed by lighthouse tool.  Is there particular test I should look for in lighthouse report ?

Comment: can you please share which website did you test ? I can test those on my end as well and update back.

Comment: I just tried Myntra.com and it installed as a PWA fine on my Android. If you are having problems with all these sites on your device then either you have already installed them (it only happens once), or some other weird issue with your device. If you ask a friend to check a new site on their device and it will probably work.

Comment: Note: Myntra.com stops the default chrome A2HS pop up. They have their own. It's the Plus sign at the top of the screen that jiggles as a hint to tell you to press on it.

Comment: Did your own website recently stop showing the A2HS popup?

Comment: I had installed once on this device; later deleted PWA and again going to their website, doesn't show me pop-up asking to install on home page. I have cleared history as well.

Comment: They are blocking the popup. Press on the Plus (+) symbol at the top of the screen to A2HS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200209/discussion-between-vikramvi-and-mathias).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case here, but from Chrome 76 on, they had a change in the beforeinstallprompt.

> Starting in Chrome 76 (July 2019), you can prevent the mini-infobar from appearing by calling preventDefault() on the beforeinstallprompt event.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  // Prevent Chrome 76 and later from showing the mini-infobar
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
  showInstallPromotion();
});
```

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners

In my case I had called the preventDefault, since it was a copy from some example. Before the Chrome update it apparently did not have that effect.

Comment: My Android phone ( 7.1.1 ) has got Chrome version ( 77.0.3865.92 ) . I need to show Install To Home Screen dialog to all the users, I didn't get your point ? Do I need to explicitly mention now that in the code ? Please clarify

Comment: If you do not include this line in your code (e.preventDefault();) the automatic chrome pop-up will show. If you want to create your own A2HS solution, you use that command.